# XML UI file isn't properly linked to Java file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I've given my buttons an OnClick attribute through XML
(e.g. `android:onClick="goToMainActivity"`). However I keep getting the error "Cannot resolve symbol".

The OnClick methods are defined in the Java file, but the XML file isn't picking them up.

Here's the XML file (fragment_chores.XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="<-"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@null"
            app:cornerRadius="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="previousWeekAction"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/monthYearTV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Feb 2021"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="->"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@null"
            app:cornerRadius="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="nextWeekAction"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="SUN"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_orange"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="MON"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_orange"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TUE"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_orange"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="WED"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_orange"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="THUR"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_orange"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="FRI"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_orange"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="SAT"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_orange"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/calendarRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Event"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@null"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        android:onClick="newEventAction"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/eventListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here how I'm linking it to the Java file (ChoresFragment.java):

```
 public class ChoresFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chores, container, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your activity? If you define onClick property, your activity must have the member function defined, like this:

```
public void previousWeekAction(View view) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Turns out that I can't give my buttons OnClick attributes this way since I'm using fragments. I had to set an OnClickListener in the Java class. Thanks for your help either way! :)